# How to register DI service with one string param

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have this class:

```
public class GraphApiEngine : IGraphApiEngine
{
    public GraphApiEngine(string name)
    {
        
    }
}

//And I registered firstly without input param name, but now I need input param name
public static IServiceCollection ConfigureEngines(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IGraphApiEngine, GraphApiEngine>();

    return services;
}
```